# Как повесить кнопку закрыть на окно которое открывается при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят есть миниатюры , при клике на которых выходит окно с спаном закрыть , как сделать чтобы при клике на спан закрыть закрывалось окно которое появляется при клике ? вот [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/h8wojdtq/) зайдите на второй таб Collection чтобы увидеть галерею

Стили кнопки "Закрыть"

```
 .close-modal{
        width:16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-image: url("http://cbmedia3.contobox.com/cbox_themes_v3/marks_fall_footwear_q4_2017/images/demoCloseBtn.png?ac=1506976312");
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 4;
        cursor: pointer;
        right: 14px;
    }
```

html

```
<div class="modal-for-photo" id="nameToClose">
                                                    <div class="modal-background"></div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body" data-pos="1">
                                                        <div class="col-demo">
                                                            <span class="close-modal" id="closeButton"></span>
                                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                                            <div class="summary">
                                                                <span class="name">
                                                                    <h3>DENVER HAYES</h3>
                                                                    <h4>MARKHAM BOOTS</h4>
                                                                </span>
                                                                <a href="#">SHOP NOW</a>
                                                            </div>
```

js

```
    document.getElementById("closeButton").addEventListener('cli‌​ck', function(){ document.getElementById("nameToClose").style.display = "none"; })
```

Comment: Пробовал onclick вешать но не получалось. как сделать addEventListener-ом ?

Answer (score 1):

При помощи чистого js просто добавь событие на кнопку. И при клике смени её состояние (стиль) на display none.

Также ты можешь использовать **jQuery** что упростит работу вот ссылка:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Вот что-то типа того что тебе нужно (взято из ссылки)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
});
```

Comment: хочу сделать на чистом js , без использования Jquery . А вот именно что не получается вешать событие

Comment: вот так добавлять listener => document.getElementById("name").addEventListener('click', function(){}); Почему вы не хотите исп. jQuery?

Comment: попробуйте прописать полный код , я думаю что не будет работать

Comment: сейчас как на чистом js все разберу , а потом уже попробую что-то новое

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67940/discussion-on-answer-by-jhonblack--------).